# Showing list of parametric plots

Tags: plotting, parameters

I can make two plots and show them , but I dont know how to make n plots and show them, example :

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{(1 - Cos[2 \[Pi] s]) Sin[2 \[Pi] s], 
  Cos[2 \[Pi] s] (Sin[2 \[Pi] s] + 1)}, {s, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Black]

p2 = ParametricPlot[{(1 - 0.5*Cos[2 \[Pi] s]) Sin[2 \[Pi] s], 
  0.5*Cos[2 \[Pi] s] (Sin[2 \[Pi] s] + 1)}, {s, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Black]

Show[p1,p2]
```

but how can I have something like (psudo code)

```
    p_a = ParametricPlot[{(1 - a*0.1*Cos[2 \[Pi] s]) Sin[2 \[Pi] s], 
      a*0.1*Cos[2 \[Pi] s] (Sin[2 \[Pi] s] + 1)}, {s, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Black]
a=1..10
Show[p_a]
```

Comment: Perhaps `Show[{p1,p2,...,pn}]` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : so if n=1..100 how do i write the second part? There must be a way to show an array of plots.

Comment: An array of plots depending on a: `Table[ Plot[somthing[a],...],{a,1,100}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also put multiple parametric curves in a single [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[
   Tooltip[
    {(1 - a/10 Cos[2 π s]) Sin[2 π s],
     a/10 Cos[2 π s] (Sin[2 π s] + 1)},
    a],
   {a, 1, 10}],
 {s, 0, 1},
 Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> Range[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    Clear["`.*"]
xyz[s_, n_] = {(1 - 1/(2 n)*Cos[2 \[Pi] s]) Sin[2 \[Pi] s], 
  1/(2 n)*Cos[2 \[Pi] s] (Sin[2 \[Pi] s] + 1), 0} ;
ParametricPlot3D[xyz[s, n], {n, .01, 4}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-.5, .5}}]
```

[image]

with $ \dfrac{1}{2 n}$ as perturbation constant. (Used 3D if needed for any generalization later and as quick visualization).